# Javascript: How to run async functions in different threads?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have an async function that returns a promise in my js code like the below;

```
async launch(){
  return new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
    let opts = {
      headless: false,
      defaultViewport: null,
      args: ['--start-maximized'],
      slowMo: 1,
      timeout: 10000
    };
    puppeteer
      .launch(opts)
      .then(function (browser) {    
        resolve(browser);
      });
  });
}
```

It launches a new browser page by using puppeteer.

#### Usage:

```
var browserLauncher = new BrowserLauncher();
var browser = await browserLauncher.launch();
var page = await browser.newPage();
```

So I would like to launch 5 browsers at the same time in different threads. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think provided details are enough. can you elaborate more on problem details like framework if any

Comment: there are no threads in javascript

Comment: @Harish You can search the puppeteer framework from the google if you don't know and I can't help you specifically because I don't understand what you don't understand.

Comment: I heard that to provide the thread mechanism they use setTimeout function but I haven't done that because of await error. @JaromandaX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `await` multiple `Promise`s with `Promise.all`. See example below:

```js
function performTask(message, timeout) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Completed ${message}`);
    }, timeout);
  });
}

(async () => {
  const allTasks = [
    performTask('first', 500),
    performTask('second', 100),
    performTask('third', 200),
  ];

  await Promise.all(allTasks);
})();
```

In your example, you could wrap up your actions in an `async` method like so:

```
async function launchBrowser(options) {
  var browserLauncher = new BrowserLauncher();
  var browser = await browserLauncher.launch();
  var page = await browser.newPage();
}

await Promise.all([
  launchBrowser({ /* options */ }),
  launchBrowser({ /* options */ }),
  launchBrowser({ /* options */ }),
  launchBrowser({ /* options */ }),
  launchBrowser({ /* options */ }),
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but when I try your solution, it returns 'await is only valid in async function' error but I have removed 'await' from the beginning of the Promise function than it is done. Thanks :)

Comment: I think I read that Chrome is now supporting top-level `await` (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await), but other browsers maybe not.

Comment: I just run it on chromium-browser so I think it is not a problem.

Comment: If you need to execute something after the `Promise.all`, you can wrap it in a self executing function. i.e. `(async () => { /* code with await */ })`... or using old school `promise.then()`.